# What can I do in Java Swing to minimize the window (and not to close it) when the user click on the "x" button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am pretty new in Java **Swing** development and I have the following problem:

I have a class named **MainFrame** that extends **JFrame** to show a simple GUI.

This window have the classic "x" and "-" buton to close and to minimize the window.

If I click on the "x" button the window will be close. I think that this is the standard behavior definied by the **JFrame** abstrac class (is it correct or am I missing something?)

What can I do if I would that when the user click on the "x" button the window is not closed but only minimized? Have I to override a method? How?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It's well understood by the user that x means close.

Comment: @Dodd10x: there are a lot of applications which just minimize themselves into the taskbar instead of closing when you click on the X - some even have an option to configure this behavior.

Comment: Aside from instant messenger programs, I can't think of any.  And those confused enough people that they need to throw up a message stating the program is still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily done. Set the frame's default close operation to "do nothing". Then provide a window listener that minimizes the frame from within the `windowClosing` method:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        ((JFrame)e.getSource()).setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }
});
```

Comment: And then the user wonders why the program won't stop running so he kills it in the task manager and stops using it.

Comment: @Dodd10x There is a specific custom button to stop and quit the application, many application work in this way, anyway it is a 
requirement of the customer

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not changing the close button behavior at all.  It's bad practice to confuse the user.  Instead, create a JFrame that is undecorated.  It will no longer have borders, close buttons, or a title.  And it won't be re-sizable, moveable, closeable, or minimizeable unless you specifically add those features in.

Comment: How is a frame that is completely uncontrollable less confusing?

Comment: You add your own buttons to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Window Listener:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SwingFrame{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    SwingFrame s = new SwingFrame();
    s.start();
}

JFrame frame;

public void start(){
    frame = new JFrame("Frame in Java Swing");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new myWindowListener());
}
class myWindowListener implements WindowListener{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("hi");
        frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){}

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){}
}
```

}